# Foreign key to 1 of several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (OrderFreshGoods and OrderUtensils) and then I have an AuditTrail table. The AuditTrail table is related to the OrderFreshGoods table but I want to change it so that an Audit must relate to either an OrderFreshGoods or OrderUtensils record. I have seen a lot of solutions where the Audit table say would have 2 foreign keys (OrderIDFresh, OrderIDUtensils and it is optional that 1 of them must be populated). Note that I do not want that solution. I want the Audit table to have 1 foreign key (OrderID) and it must relate to either OrderFreshGoods.OrderID or OrderUtensils.OrderID.

Also my two order tables have no fields in common and are used in a large number of queries around the system so I don't want a parent table for both types of order.

Can anybody help? My sql script is below, the comments should help explain my tests...

```
--Setup tables
create table OrderFreshGoods (OrderID int not null primary key, sellBy date, name varchar(20))
go
create table OrderUtensils (OrderID int not null primary key, requiresOver18CheckForKnives bit, colour varchar(20), title varchar(20))
go
create table AuditTrail (AuditId int not null primary key, OrderID int, timeOfEvent date, eventDescription varchar(100))
go

--Base data
insert into OrderFreshGoods values (7, DATEADD(dd, 3, getdate()), 'Organic milk')
insert into OrderUtensils values (8, 0, 'Red', 'Garlic crusher')

--Test data!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
--This should work
insert into AuditTrail values (15, 7, getdate(), 'Logging order for Organic Milk from Corkys Coffee shop.')
--This should work
insert into AuditTrail values (16, 8, getdate(), 'Logging order for a Red Garlic Crusher from Perrys Pizza Place.')
--This should not be allowed
insert into AuditTrail values (17, 9, getdate(), 'Wrongly adding an audit entry before the order, please stop me now!')
--This should not be allowed
insert into AuditTrail values (18, null, getdate(), 'Oh dear, bad code has caused the OrderId to be lost, please stop me now!')
```

Comment: I'd go with a trigger based solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible as you describe it, it goes against the very premise of Relational databases.

If you leave out the actual Foreign Key, then you can populate the `AuditTrail.OrderId` with whatever you want.
But you'd lose the referential integrity check, so your third `insert into AuditTrail` statement wouldn't fail. That could then be fixed by applying an on-insert trigger which does a reference check. But it would still not prevent Orders from being deleted, causing the pseudo-relation to go bad again.

Another and perhaps much better alternative is to add an `AuditId` field to both of the Order tables, and fill that as needed.

Comment: Thanks Peter, what I am trying to also consider is that a number of new Order<whatever> tables will be added in future. That's why I don't want the solution with a common table as this requires re-work each time. This leaves your solution of adding AuditID to every order table. This might be my solution because as you point out, preventing bad data going in doesn't prevent data from being deleted or updated later. Preventing that would take more work and I would be safer using foreign keys. Because your answer is so well reasoned, I'm marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use always proper relations, then I can see next solution:

1. create yet another table xxxx, like:

   `create table xxxx(id int identity(1,1) primary key)`
2. add foreign keys in all your auditable tables to xxxx(id)
3. create new records in xxxx while adding records to auditable tables (triggers can be handy) (you may include more info into xxxx)
4. add foreign key in audit table to xxxx(id)

This way you can insert into audit table only records, pointing to xxxx - and these are always related to actual orders (and do not vanish when some order gets deleted either).